# PHP Classes: Define default return object

Tags: php, class, return

I have a PHP Class with a Constructor and some Methods. Every Method need to have the same return stdClass Object. Only a few properties in each functoin of the stdClass Object should be diffrent from the default one(like the property `value` or `status`). How would you do that? I mean, i can define in every function an stdClass Object with all properties, but as I said, I only need to change a few properties in each function for the return.

Examplecode which **doesn't** work:

```
<?
    class Person{
        public $sName;
        public $oReturn = new stdClass();
        $oReturn->status = 200;
        $oReturn->value = "Personname";

        function __construct($sName) {
            $this->sName = $sName;
        }

        public function something($oData){
            //Declaration
            $this->oReturn->value = $oData->newName;
            //Main

            //Return
            return $this->oReturn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Classes can be extended using ``extends`` keyword.

Comment: Why don't you create a parent class with all the properties and all your classes `extends` from it?. I don't understand your question... take a look to this http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: Look at my updated question. I wanted it something like this, but this isn't working. As you can see, I have a default return value. In the function `something` I change the default value. This is all what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare properties like this:-

```
public $oReturn = new stdClass();
```

That is illegal in PHP. Do it like this:-

```
class Person{
    public $sName;
    public $oReturn;

    function __construct($sName) {
        $this->sName = $sName;
        $this->oReturn = new stdClass;
        $this->oReturn->status = 200;
        $this->oReturn->value = "Personname";
    }

    public function something($oData){
        //Declaration
        $this->oReturn->value = $oData->newName;
        //Main

        //Return
        return $this->oReturn;
    }
}
```

Now you can set whatever properties you want in `$this->oReturn` which, I think, is what you want to achieve.

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/ibaLL)

Answer (score 0):

You could just return a shared method that formats the data for you.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    protected
        $defaults = array(
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2,
        );

    protected function reply(array $params = null) {
        $properties = $this->defaults;

        if ($params) {
            $properties = array_merge($properties, $params);
        }

        return (object) $properties;
    }

    public function a($a) {
        return $this->reply(array('a' => $a));
    }

    public function b($b) {
        return $this->reply(array('b' => $b));
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
var_dump($foo->a('a'));
var_dump($foo->b('b'));

/*
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(1) "a"
      ["b"]=>
      int(2)
    }

    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["a"]=>
      int(1)
      ["b"]=>
      string(1) "b"
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after method chaining. You can create a class whose methods return `$this`, and then you can change your method calls.

Consider a class like the following:

```
<?php
class User
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $email;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
$user->setName('Martin')->setEmail('martin@example.com');
```

After this, your `User` class’s properties will reflect what values you’ve assigned to them in your chained method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign *non-scalar* values to class properties *after* class instantiation(AKA after `new`). See that the `$oReturn` value assignment is moved into the constructor.

```
class Person{
    public $sName;
    public $oReturn;
    protected $default_status = 200;
    protected $default_value = "Personname";

    function __construct($sName) {
        $this->sName = $sName;
        $this->oReturn = new stdClass();
        $this->oReturn->status = $this->default_status;
        $this->oReturn->value = $this->default_value;
    }

    public function something($oData){
        //Declaration
        $this->oReturn->value = $oData->newName;
        //Main

        //Return
        return $this->oReturn;
    }
}
```

Now, you can extend this class, to make small variations.

```
class PersonNotFound extends Person {
    protected $default_status = 404;
    protected $default_value = 'NotFound';
}
```

Let's see their results:

```
$oData = new stdClass();
$oData->newName = 'Neo';

$person_a = new Person("Triniti");
var_dump( $person_a->something($oData) );
// status = 200

$person_b => new PersonNotFound("Cyon");
var_dump( $person_b->something($oData) );
// status = 404
```

### EDIT:

Constructor injection version:

```
class Person{
    public $sName;
    public $oReturn;

    function __construct($sName, $status = 200, $value = "Personname") {
        $this->sName = $sName;
        $this->oReturn = new stdClass();
        $this->oReturn->status = $status;
        $this->oReturn->value = $value;
    }

    public function something($oData){
        $this->oReturn->value = $oData->newName;
        return $this->oReturn;
    }
}

$person_a = new Person("Neo"); // 200, Personname as default
$person_b = new Person("Triniti", 404, "NotFound");
```

Comment: I like the method in the answer from `vascowhite`. Is an extends Class in my example needless?